# Dynamically create PDFs and email them

Tags: php, pdf-generation, email-attachments

I've got a registration list, which I need to send out a PDF to each person on the list. Each email needs to contain a PDF, which has a base version on the server, but each person's needs to be personalized via name/company etc over the top. This needs to be emailed to each person, which at the moment adds up to be 2,500, but can easily be much higher in the future.

I've only just started working on this project, but the problem I've encountered continuously since last week are that the server doesn't seem to be able to handle doing this. Currently the script is using Zend, which then allows it to use Zend_Pdf and Zend_Mail to create and email the PDFs. Zend_mail connects to an smtp server from smtp.com to do the actual emailing.

Since we have quite a few sites running on the server, we can't afford it to be going down, and when I run it in batches it can start to go down. The best solution I have thus far is running curl from my local machine to the script, which then does one person. The curl script then calls it again, over and over in batches. Even this runs into problems at times, and seems to some how hog memory even after it should be complete (I'm really not sure how).

So what I'm looking for is information on doing this, from libraries, code, information on server setups, anything that can make this much less painful, and much quicker for us to run. I've run out of ideas, and this is something I've not really had to do before (especially at a bulk level).

Thank you.

Edit:

I also forgot to mention that it's using zend_barcode::factory for creating a barcode on the PDF.

Comment: Is the email sent real-time, like after a form submit?

Comment: No, we're trying to send it as a batch. So we pull a list from a database, grab the next user who hasn't had their PDF sent, and create the PDF then email it as an attachment, in one script.

Comment: I don't know how to really pick an answer here, as I didn't get the chance to try any of these, but I will have to go through this all again in 5 or 6 months, from my understanding, so I will be back here a few months before that to try these out AHEAD of time. I'd like to thank everyone who commented and left ideas, you've all given me a great head start and some things to think about and try. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

First step I suggest is to work out where the problem lies if you can.  Is it the PDF generation? Is it the emailing?  "Server doesn't seem to be able to handle this" doesn't say what is actually failing as with the "server goes down" - you need to determine if you are running out of memory/disk-space/time or something else.  That will help you determine if you need a tweak or a new approach to your generation.  Because you said that even single manual invocations can fail you should be able to narrow the problem down to exactly what is the cause of the failure.

If you are running near some resource limit (which might be the case with several sites running), you probably need to offload this capability onto another machine.  Your options include:

1. run the same setup on a new host and adjust your applications to use the new system
2. run a new setup on a new host
3. use an external system (such as the mentioned PDFCrowd or [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com))

Start with the specifics of the problem.  I hope that helps.  Please note I work for the company that created Docmosis.

Comment: Yeah, I know I missed out what was causing it, but at the moment, we're running it the slow way and monitoring it, so I don't really have the chance to test it. I've only been working here a week, and don't even have a local version of it to mess with. Based on what I see, my gut says it's all in the PDF creation and the barcode creation, but I can't be sure of this, of course.

Comment: Sounds like a tough start to a new job.  Hopefully your monitoring will turn up what is failing (memory/disk etc) and that will help you decide what's next

Comment: Very tough, never been so stressed as a web developer in my life, I'll be looking into it as soon as this batch of emails is done and can have a chance to mess with it more.

Answer (score 0):

**From my experience - two options:**

Dynamically generate PDFs using one or more PDF libraries (which can be awfully slow).

**OR**

Use something like [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) which is a simple shell utility to convert html to pdf using the webkit rendering engine, and qt.

Basically, you can loop over *n* HTML pages and generate PDF's without the overhead of purely dynamic PDF generation!

We've used this to distribute thousands of personalised PDF's on a daily basis as it quickly converts HTML pages to PDF. There are dependencies, but it works and is less intensive (computationally) than 'creating' PDFs individually.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure I'm in a position to be able to set that up on our hosting environment. It's a dedicated server, but it is still a hosted service we don't have 100% control over.

Comment: If it's a dedicated server, the least you can do is ask for the packages/required dependencies to be installed!? If they're worth their fee, they should be able to install it for you - unless they give compelling reasons not to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some ideas:

1. Is there a particular reason this has to run on a web server?  Why not run the framework 
   from a different machine, but with the same settings?  You might have to create a different 
   controller to handle the command-line version of the request, but there's no fundamental 
   reason it can't work.
2. If creating PDFs programatically is giving you a headache, you can instead use a service.
   In the past, I've used [PDFCrowd](http://pdfcrowd.com/) with good results, and they provided 
   a useful PHP library.  You can give them a blob of HTML, using full URLs for any stylesheets 
   and images, and they'll create a PDF for you.

   The cost per document varies from 0.5-4.5 cents per document depending on your rate plan.

   There are other services which do the same thing.
3. If this kind of batch job is a big deal for your company, you might consider an 
   asynchronous job queue like [beanstalk](http://kr.github.com/beanstalkd/).  You could queue 
   up thousands of these, and a worker script could handle the requests at whatever pace you 
   deem reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to call the script over HTTP, the script will timeout based on the max_execution_time specified in the php.ini.

You need to write a php script which can be run from command line and then schedule it via a cron job.  The script at a time, can read one user, put together his pdf file, and email him. After that, you might have to run some performance checks to see if the server can handle the process.

Comment: Yeah I tried cron jobbing the script, and had the same issue, in fact it was slightly worse because I couldn't work out how to make cron rerun whenever it got a response rather than every X minutes. I've also set a longer timeout on both my local curl request and the server that runs the script to allow them to complete. The only reason it'd ever not finish running is server overload/crash.